# How to send commands from iPhone to a hardware device?

Tags: iphone, hardware-interface

I have been assigned a project in which I need to send commands to hardware device. The hardware device is supporting CAN Bus command control.

Comment: How does the iPhone interface to the hardware device?

Comment: using wifi , hardware device supporting the wifi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn about ExternalAccessory framework.

Go through [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ExternalAccessoryPT/Introduction/Introduction.html) to learn about about ExternalAccessory programming.

Comment: can you provide a good link for understanding the CANBus commands